# error in loading contourf

Tags: matlab, contourf

I recently encountered this error when updating to ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I cannot understand what is going on. Suspecting a PATH/LIBRARY etc. error. Similar happens when trying to load programs that I used with MCR. What could be the problem? These errors are common, but all of them at the same time, it is hard to find an answer as well. Thanks in advance.

when i use

> > Z = peaks(20); >> contourf(Z,10)

I get these:

```
No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoUpdateColorAction (line 209) if h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoUpdateColorAction (line 209) if h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoMarkDirtyAction (line 244) if h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoModeSwitchAction (line 195) if strcmp(get(h,modeprop),'auto') && h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoModeSwitchAction (line 195) if strcmp(get(h,modeprop),'auto') && h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoUpdateColorAction (line 209) if h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoUpdateChildrenAction (line 201) if h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoModeSwitchAction (line 195) if strcmp(get(h,modeprop),'auto') && h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoModeSwitchAction (line 195) if strcmp(get(h,modeprop),'auto') && h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoModeSwitchAction (line 195) if strcmp(get(h,modeprop),'auto') && h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No appropriate method, property, or field initialized for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup/schema>LdoModeSwitchAction (line 195) if strcmp(get(h,modeprop),'auto') && h.initialized

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. > In specgraph.contourgroup.contourgroup at 19 In contourf at 79 No public field initialized exists for class specgraph.contourgroup.

Error in specgraph.contourgroup (line 20) h.initialized = 1;

Error in contourf (line 79) h = specgraph.contourgroup('Parent', parax, 'Fill', 'on', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring MATLAB to its default search path by using:

```
>>restoredefaultpath;
>>rehash toolboxcache;
```

Try using contourf now. If it works, save the path settings, using:

```
>>savepath;
```

You will need to add your custom folders back to the MATLAB path yourself as this will restore MATLAB to its default path settings.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I dont understand i did a clean install as well under default folder /usr/local/MATLAB. I dont understand. Is it possible that i am doing something wrong in the installation? It was pretty straightforward